# Combine lines in a text file of Linux server with condition

Tags: linux, perl, grep

I have records as follows in text file on a Linux server -

```
telephone = 1111
a=1
b=2
telephone = 2222
a=1
b=2
c=3
telephone = 3333
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
```

I need it be like this -

```
telephone = 1111, a=1, b=2
telephone = 2222, a=1, b=2, c=3
telephone = 3333, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4
```

Grep or perl command both are ok whatever can help to get the results.

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR)].

Comment: Using `gnu awk` `awk 'NR>1 {$1=RS$1;print}' OFS=", " RS="telephone = " file`

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have your input in `input.txt` file, try the following:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print /^telephone/ ? "\n$_" : ", $_" } { print "\n"' input.txt
```

EDIT: to prevent newline at the start:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print !/^telephone/ ? ", $_" : $. > 1 ? "\n$_" : "$_" } { print "\n"' input.txt
```

Comment: This gives a blank line at start.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print !/^telephone/ ? ", " : $. > 1 ? "\n" : ""; print' file.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: This miss a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done conveniently with **awk**:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { buf = $0; next } /^telephone/ { print buf; buf = $0; next } { buf = buf ", " $0 } END {print buf}' input.txt
```

This one-liner can probably be further shortened, though...

**EDIT**: Yes it can, taking in consideration the way awk builds boolean values from strings:

```
awk '/^telephone/ { if(buf) print buf; buf = $0; next } { buf = buf ", " $0 } END {print buf}' input.txt
```

**EDIT2**: I add my **sed** solution, which does not require the limb-twisting seen in ooga's solution:

```
sed -f myscript input.txt
```

where `myscript` is as follows:

```
#n
/^telephone/ {
  x
  s/\n/, /gp
  g
  n
  }
H
$ {
  g
  s/\n/, /gp
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even `sed` can do this.

```
sed '
  $ {H; b output}
  {
    s/telephone/&/
    t output
      H
      d
    : output
      x
      s/\n/, /g
  }
  1d
' file
```